# Form not passing any values

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form that I'm submitting using jQuery `$.post()`. It doesn't submit any variables.

Here's the jQuery code:

```
 $('#eb1').live('click',function() {
        $.post("php/emailPost.php", $("emailPost").serialize(), function(){
            $("#emailModal").dialog('close');
            $('#emailJQButton').attr('value', 'Emailed');
        });
});
```

The post file returns no errors, and everything else is working fine. It's only the fact that no values are passed (I checked with Firebug).

Here's a portion of the PHP code outputting the form itself (don't say anything about HEREDOC, it does not work for me, case closed):

```
echo "<form action='php/emailPost.php' method='POST' class='inline' id='emailPost'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' value='" . $_SESSION["email"] . "' name='emailAddress'>";
echo "<input type='button' value='Email To Me' id='eb1'/>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='passedCoupID' value='" . $coupID . "'/>";
echo "</form>";
```

I don't see anything obvious why it doesn't pass any values. Other similarly-written forms pass variables correctly. `$coupID` is pre-populated by the page.

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("emailPost").serialize()
```

Should be

```
$("#emailPost").serialize()
```

Answer (score 2):

change

```
$("emailPost").serialize()
```

to

```
$("#emailPost").serialize()
```

or

```
$("form").serialize()
```